# How to first POST request when payload is availble?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a success page that is shown after an successful payment. The URL has a query parameter. When it is loaded i want to POST the query param to my api endpoint. My Problem is, that the first POST request is empty (router.query = {}). When the useEffect is triggered everytime (which means that it sends more than one POST request), the second POST request contains the query param. How can I make it, that it only posts when there is an actuall query param, so it doesn't send and empty POST request.

This is my code:

```
const Success = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(DataContext);

  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(async ()=>{
    await postData('order/decreaseInStock', router.query)
  },[]) // when i remove the [] the first POST req is still empty but the second and those after contain the correct param
  
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col h-screen items-center'>
            <div className='flex mt-60 flex-col items-center p-12 py-16 bg-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-xl'>
                <h1 className='text-green-400 text-5xl font-extrabold'>
                    Takk for din bestilling!
                </h1>
                <Link href='/'>
                    <div className='flex items-center mt-9 cursor-pointer'>
                        <ArrowLeft />
                        <a>Tilbake</a>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you only want to POST when there is something in the query params, you could do something like.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // This will trigger your api call if any query params exists. 
  // This can be more finegrained to only trigger if all your params are present.
  if (Object.keys(router.query).length) {
    postData('order/decreaseInStock', router.query)
  }
}, [router.query])
```